# Django Admin - Show form json input value as text insted string

Tags: django

Considering I have a model like:

```
MyStore = (
id = 1,
name = 'Foobar',
information_as_json = {
    'open_at': datetime.now(),
    'close_at': datetime.now() + timedelta('+1 day'),
    'workers' : {
        'Person1' : 'Owner',
        'Person2' : 'Boss',
        'Person3' : 'Boss',
    }
})
```

Inside Django admin forms, for every field is generated an input, but for the field "information_as_json", I don't want to show it as a string or as JSON. That is because the users who are accessing this store admin page, need to read the field 'information_as_json' easier since no one can edit these values because it is generated in another part of the application.

Is it possible to convert these values to a "div" or a plain text? The contents would be:

> This store opens at: *{information_as_json.open_at}*

> This store close at: *{information_as_json.close_at}*

And for the workers, iterate through keys and values:

```
for key, value in information_as_json.workers:
```

> Worker {key} has the role: *{value}*

I'm a beginner at Django, so I'm struggling a little with this part.

Every help would be appreciated :D

Comment: Would this be similar to help text (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#help-text) on model fields?

Comment: It's a little bit, this field "information" would contain more information in the future, so I am trying to convert this to a "box", so it would be easier to implement the text inside this box when new information is added.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to get a handle on what you're describing. Would you be able to post an example model and field of what this would ideally look like in your Python code and maybe a mockup of what you expect to be rendered?

Comment: I have edited my post, take a look :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest approaching the model a little differently. Rather than storing the opening and closing hours as JSON they can just be fields directly on the store model. The the workers can be a [JSONfield [docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) containing name/role pairs. If you're using PostgreSQL for your database you could even use [HStoreField [docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield), which might be more appropriate.

Here's how I would write a similar model.

```py
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True)
    workers = models.JSONField(blank=True, default=dict, editable=False)

    closing = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    opening = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

To display the details in the Django admin we just need to define a property which returns the correct string.

```py
    @mark_safe
    def details(self):
        roles = [
            f'{x} has the role: {y}'
            for x, y in self.workers.items()
        ]
        return '<br>'.join([
            f'This store opens at: {self.opening:%-H:%M}',
            f'This store closes at: {self.closing:%-H:%M}',
        ] + roles)
```

This method can then be referenced in the `ModelAdmin` and used like a read-only field.

```py
@admin.register(Store)
class StoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'opening', 'closing']
    fields = ['name', 'details']
    readonly_fields = ['details']
```

[image: Using a method in the Django admin as a read-only field]

Comment: Thank you very much @Jacinator! I learned a lot from your answer, my code is much better and cleaner too, didn't know that I can create a "fake field" using `def details(self)`.

Again, thank you very much!!!!